# Golang timestamp parsing

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse the timestamp `Oct 12 2016 13:59:27 UTC` using the following code.

```
eventDateLayout := "Jan _2 2006 15:04:00 UTC"
eventCheckDate, _ := time.Parse(eventDateLayout,"Oct 12 2016 13:59:27 UTC")
fmt.Println(eventCheckDate)
```

Result if `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` which is not the expected.

Can this timestamp parsed with golang time library?

Comment: `"Jan _2 2006 15:04:05 UTC"`

Comment: @tkausl it worked! thanks.

Comment: @AnuruddhaPremalal the error (which you are ignoring) is telling you where the problem is.

Comment: why is the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the incorrect time layout, I'd recommend handling the error instead of throwing it away.

It gives you a helpful error message that you can use to efficiently debug:

`cannot parse "27 UTC" as ":00 UTC"`

[Go playground (note the outputted time will be different)](https://play.golang.org/p/kvW1_3ASge)